# how to load balance api backend on different ports with pm2

Tags: node.js, api, express, pm2

Let's say I have a simple api backend that listens on port 3000

```
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello, World!');
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('API listening on port 3000');
});
```

I want to load balance this, so I'm using pm2 for that

```
pm2 npm start --name apis -i 2 -- start
```

`pm2 ls` shows me 2 instances running in cluster mode, but one's errored out because port 3000 is being used by the first instance (obviously)

in this case, what's the right way for me to load balance or specify different ports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found a way.

pm2 has an option to increment variables with each instance, so with this config, my backends started on incremented ports each

```json
module.exports = {
    apps: [
        {
            name: "apis",
            script: "npm",
            args: "start",
            instances: 4,
            exec_mode: "cluster",
            increment_var: "PORT",
            env: {
                PORT: 3000,
            },
        },
    ],
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [PM2 ecosystem](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/) instead of running manual commands.

```
// index.js
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello, World!');
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('API listening on port 3000');
});
```

```
// ecosystem.config.js
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: "apis",
      script: "index.js",
      instances: "2",
      autorestart: true,
      max_memory_restart: "1G",
      env: {
        PORT: 3000,
      },
    }
  ]
}
```

Start the project by running: `pm2 start ecosystem.config.js`

For more about [pm2 multiple instance](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/cluster-mode/)

Comment: both of the instances will try to use the same port, and thus won't work